# $\log\Gamma(z)$ formula to deduce an estimate

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

I currently want to show
$$
\log\Gamma(z)=(z-1/2)\log z-z+\frac{1}{2}\log2\pi+\int_0^\infty \frac{[u]-u+1/2}{u+z}du.
$$
where $[u]$ denotes the floor function. Here, $z$ is a complex variable.

Could anyone provide a hint? This comes from Murty's Problems in Analytic Number Theory Exercise 6.3.13, but I do not want to look in the back of the book for the solution.

What I have tried thus far is to take the Hadamard factorization of $1/\Gamma(z)$, take the logarithm, and try to estimate the series that comes out of it. Unfortunately, what I get is
$$
\log\Gamma(z)=-\gamma z-\log z+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(1+\frac{z}{n})}{n}.
$$
Here, the series isn't easy to work with. I tried partial summation but it doesn't provide me with any reasonable approach for estimate.

I have a few more ideas on approaches, but am posting this question in case I come back empty handed.

Thanks!

Comment: This is Stirling formula with explicit  remainder, though one has to be careful of its domain of application (which is the plane minus  the negative real axis pointwise, but a wedge uniformly); usually one proves it by denoting by $f(z)$ the exponential of the right hand side and showing that it is well defined, analytic and satisfies the same functional equation as Gamma plus the required vertical boundness in the strip from $1$ to $2$ which  characterizes Gamma  uniquely  up to a multiplicative constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral begs for $\int_0^\infty=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{n-1}^n$ and summation by parts (even without the book at hand).

More conceptually though, it looks like a remainder of the [Euler–Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula): $$\sum_{n=0}^N f(n)=\int_0^N f(x)\,dx+\frac{f(0)+f(N)}{2}+\int_0^N f'(x)\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor-\frac12\right)dx$$ for, say, $f\in C^1[0,N]$, applied to $f(x)=\log(x+z)$, *assuming $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leqslant 0}$ fixed*. To make things easy, we let $z\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and rely on analytic continuation elsewhere. Let $$I_N=\int_0^N\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor-x+1/2}{x+z}\,dx;$$ then, computing all the other pieces of the formula, we get $$I_N=\left(N+z+\frac12\right)\log(N+z)-\left(z-\frac12\right)\log z-N-\sum_{n=0}^N\log(z+n).$$

The connection to $\Gamma$ (basically the idea behind [Euler's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Euler%27s_definition_as_an_infinite_product)) is the formula $$\Gamma(z)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{N^z N!}{z(z+1)\cdots(z+N)}$$ (a proof is obtained by computing $\int_0^1\big[N(1-x^{1/N})\big]^z\,dx$ and taking $N\to\infty$).

Thus $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}I_N=\log\Gamma(z)-(z-1/2)\log z+\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}L_N$, where $$L_N=\left(N+z+\frac12\right)\log\frac{N+z}{N}+\log\frac{N^N e^{-N}\sqrt{N}}{N!}.$$ The first term tends to $z$ as $N\to\infty$, and the second tends to $-\frac12\log(2\pi)$ by Stirling's formula.

*Not sure if this is elementary enough. Compared to the suggestion by @Conrad in his comment, this doesn't use any not-that-hard-to-prove characterizations of $\Gamma$, but I've decided to use the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula, which is nice to have at hand (including a proof).*

Comment: This is indeed elementary enough. I never did manage to figure out. The observation with the remainder term of Euler-Maclaurin is very insightful! Thank you.